# Migrated Virtual Machine Shows Up in Both Datastores

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, datastore

We're using Vsphere client 4.0.0 Build 208111 with Virtual Center Server same version and same build.

I have one vm with only one disk that is shown on 2 different datastores. If I look through VMs and Templates I see only 1 vm. If I look through Datastores screen, I see it in datastore-002 and datastore-003. If I go to settings of the virtual machine on datastore-002 and check the disk, I see the path as datastore-003.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Hi

On which datastore is the vmdk (.vmdk and -flat.vmdk)?

did the migration of the virtual machine raise any error or was it successfull?

Did you do a *datastore migration* or did you migrate the vm onto another host?

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on both of those datastores and verify whether there's a folder in each one called *VMNAME*.

If there's a folder in only 1, then you probably have an ISO mounted on the VM and it's located on the second datastore.

If there's a folder for the VM in both datastores, check inside and see if both folders have a .vmdk inside. If they both have the disk VMDK file, then you probably got in a situation where a storage vMotion didn't completely finish up and the old files were left hanging around on the old datastore. This happens a fair bit. To fix, right-click the VM and select 'Edit Settings'. Select the hard disk device, and make a note of the datastore it's on. You can then safely delete the VMDK in the *other* datastore.

It's also possible to have a VM's configuration files on one datastore, and the VMDK hard drive file on another datastore. So if you find a folder for the VM in both locations, see if one of them has the .vmx, and the other one has the .vmdk. You can easily get around this problem by storage vMotioning the VM to an entirely different datastore.

Answer (score 2):

This can occur if you have, e.g., an ISO image mounted from a particular datastore.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it can occur if you have an ISO mounted at all. Strangely the ISO doesn't need to be on the same datastore, at least with ESXi-5.5. I suspect there's a lockfile or an in-memory record that doesn't get changed during Storage VMotion.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I saw where a Serial device was installed on a particular LINUX VM.  It was not connected.  Upon further inspection, the original datastore still contained a single file: "serial.log."

I simply highlighted the device, and changed the DS directory where it's "output file" was set for.  I changed it from the old DS to the new DS where I migrated it to.

In this case, it wasn't the common, "mounted ISO", or "snapshot" that was the issue.